# Database is not being updated with Textbox values on button click event

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf, textbox

I have an SQL update command for some `Textboxes` and `Comboboxes`. However, when the event is fired the database is not getting updated with the `Textboxes` and I am not getting any exception errors.

The line in particular that I am having an issue with is `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_CMMNT", txt_ResolutionNotes.Text);`

Here is my code:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [hb_Disputes] SET FR_DSP_CLSF=@FR_DSP_CLSF, FR_CUST_CNTCT=@FR_CUST_CNTCT, FR_WRK_REQ=@FR_WRK_REQ, FR_OPN_ERR=@FR_OPN_ERR, FR_SO_TP=@FR_SO_TP, FR_SO_DTLS=@FR_SO_DTLS, FR_CMMNT=@FR_CMMNT, FR_SO_DT_WNTD=@FR_SO_DT_WNTD, FINADJ=@FINADJ, SERTYPE=@SERTYPE, CALLRSN=@CALLRSN, SECCAUSE=@SECCAUSE, MTR=@MTR, RPTTYPE=@RPTTYPE, PRMCAUSE=@PRMCAUSE WHERE DSP_ID=@DSP_ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DSP_ID", txt_RowRecrd.Text);

            // Second Row
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_DSP_CLSF", cmb_DisputeClassification.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_CUST_CNTCT", cmb_CustomerContact.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_WRK_REQ", cmb_requestedwork.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_OPN_ERR", cmb_OpenInError.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_TP", cmb_ServiceOrderType.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_DTLS", cmb_ServiceOrderDetails.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_CMMNT", txt_ResolutionNotes.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FR_SO_DT_WNTD", DatePicker_ScheduledFor.Text);

            // Third Row
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RPTTYPE", cmb_UtilityRptTyp.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FINADJ", cmb_FinancialAdjustment.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERTYPE", cmb_ServiceTypeAdjustment.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CALLRSN", cmb_InitialCallReason.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRMCAUSE", cmb_PrimCause.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECCAUSE", cmb_UnderlyingCause.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MTR", cmb_MeterIssue.SelectedValue);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();

            MessageBox.Show("Data updated!");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: As an aside best not to use [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: So have set a breakpoint on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and inspected every parameter value and then tried the exact same query from SSMS?